# deciding when to read data from network vs when to read from the cache

Tags: android

My application consists of the following activities

1. Activity A --> Connects to a web server and obtains a list of users. It also caches the list in the database so as to provide offline access as well as not making repetitive http requests to the server.
2. Clicking on item in Activity A displays Activity B which contains information related to the user. It is also cached in the database.

Currently, I decide to make the request to the server for getting the list of users only if no data is present in the database or if the onCreate method of activity A is called. Following is the code snippet for it

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    int numOfUsers = dbHelper.numOfUsers(); //Retrieve the count of users
    if (numOfUsers <= 0 || isOnCreateCalled) {
       // retrieve the list of users from the server
       // Update the database with the new values
    } else {
        // retrieve the list of users from the database
    }
  }
```

A similar approach is used to cache the user-related data present in Activity B.

I was wondering are there any better strategies than this simple approach to decide **when to read data from the network and invalidate the cached database data versus when to read from the cache**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question will depend on the use case, but the question here is can you show stale data to the user and how important is that? If it's not that important, then what you have works great. If you'd like a more robust strategy, I would recommend using GCM, Google Cloud Messaging. With GCM, your server can send you "tickles" when there's fresh data. Your app can then respond to the "tickle" and fetch all the latest data from your server. The good thing about this is that you can keep your database up-to-date even when the user isn't running your app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this kind of functionality comes built-in. There are libraries like [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) that will cache network I/O based on the parameters you set. However, you're best bet is probably to build your own solution, use something along the lines of HTTP headers, [Entity Tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), etc. Maybe you can always make a request to the server for some tiny serialized data, compare the results, and determine from there whether or not to make additional requests.

Short answer: there's lots of ways!